# Lat/Long to SVG world map

Tags: svg, geospatial, polygon

I’m trying to draw searouts on a map that is going to print. I want to use a world map in SVG, and the routs I have as lat/long coordinates (polylines).
The problem is that I can’t seem to find a working solution with 1: A world map in SVG, preferably in Mercator or Robinson projections and 2: the formula to add lat/long points to them. Or a Python library or similar that does this.

The closesed i have come is this:

https://www.jetpunk.com/tools/place-dots

which does it, but dont provide any code. Or this

https://github.com/papulovskiy/nugsl-worldmap

But here the install does not work.

Any suggestions would be much obliged.